# How should i be generating a random number between 0 and up to 2? BCL Random is not random

Tags: c#, .net

How should i be generating a random number between 0 and up to 2?

I am currently using a private static readonly Random object and call _random.Next(0, 2) BUT the values are not random ... I see sequences of 0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,,1,1,1

The below is clearly not random. How should I be doing this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: please explain why you think it is not random.....

Comment: This probably stems from a misconception of what random is. I suspect he/she wants it to be more uniform. But okay, it's not random, only pseudorandom :)

Comment: Obligatory xkcd reference: http://xkcd.com/221/

Comment: Try to generate one million of 0,1 it that way. Then count how many 0's you have and divide it by 1 million, you will get ~0.5. That's what a uniform (pseudo)random distribuition supposed to yield...

Comment: @Skurmedel: Given a purely mechanical universe, define random :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you mean you want random **numbers 0 or 1,** then what you’re doing is already correct.

If you want **numbers 0, 1 or 2**, then you need to write `_random.Next(0, 3)`.

Answer (score 3):

You are already doing it the right way (as long as your requirements for pseudo-random numbers doesn't include cryptographic security).

The problem is that randomness is statistically determined (using math), not intuitively determined (using your eyes).

For example, even if your random number sequence is uniformly random, given an infinite sequence of random numbers, you will still see one-hundred-thousand 1s in a row.

See [this Wikipedia article on Pseudorandom Number Generators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator)

If you are trying to get the numbers "0, 1, 2", then you may need to change your call to `random.Next(0, 3)`.  If you indeed only want 0 and 1, then leave it as it is.

Also, if you are creating instances of `Random` in multiple places in your code, you may get identical seeds, so will get identical sequences of random numbers.  One way to avoid this would be to reuse the instance of the `Random` class between those two pieces of code, rather than creating new instances.

Answer (score 1):

If you initialize `Random` with the same seed, you will get the same sequence of numbers. That's why it might be a good idea to use a time-based seed:

```
Random _random = new Random(DateTime.UtcNow.Millisecond);
```

Also, note that the upper bound in `Next` is *exclusive*. That means that `Next(0, 2)` will always return only 0 or 1 (but that might be what you wanted; somewhat unclear to me from the question).

Comment: The default constructor uses a time based seed.  Not sure what resolution of time, though.  Also, if `DateTime.UtcNow.Milliseconds` is anything like Win32 timing functions, it may not have as much resolution as you might think it would, which could be a problem when creating multiple instances of `Random`.

Comment: @Merilyn: Regarding the resolution of `DateTime.UtcNow.Millisecond` I am not sure of it (even though on my machine it seems to actually resolve down to each millisecond, somewhat surprisingly, I expected to see somewhere around each 15 milliseconds or so); I used it only as a simple example of a time-based seed.

Answer (score 1):

The maxValue is "upto-and-not-included". If you wish to include 2, just write _random.Next(0,3)